# Required no Ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

Possuo um código que preciso que ao ser submetido, alguns campos sejam obrigatórios serem preenchidos, tipo o `required` em html só que em Ajax, ao invés dele usar o alert como estou usando, ele use o `required` como no html. Segue o meu código abaixo:

```js
function d(func){
   var nome = $('#nome').val();
   var data = $('#data_oco').val();
   var tipo = $('#tipo').val(); 
   var justificativa = $('#justificativa').val();
   if(justificativa==undefined){
    justificativa="";
   }else if(justificativa=="" && tipo!="Falta"){
    alert("Por favor preencha o campo Justificativa!");
   }
   jQuery.ajax({
    method: "get",
    url: "atudel.php",
    data: { "nome": nome, "data": data, "tipo": tipo, "justificativa": justificativa, "func": func },
    success: function(data){
     alert(data);
     window.location = 'editar_ocorrencia.php';
    }
   });
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cabesalho_formulario">
    <h1 id="titulo">Controle Geral de Alunos <span>(Edição)</span></h1>
    <h4 id="nome_escola">EEEP Dr. José Alves da Silveira</h4>
    <div id="atualiza" class="modal fade">
     <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Atualizar/Deletar Ocorrência</h4>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-body">
          <br class='b'><label id='just'>Justificativa: </label><br class='b'><textarea required placeholder='Digite a justificativa do aluno...' title='Seja objetivo(a).' rows='5' name = 'obs' cols='50' id='justificativa'></textarea>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="d('atualiza')">Atualizar</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="d('deleta')">Deletar</button>
                 </div>
         </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Ao invés disso, ele fique assim, só que de forma que use o jquery dentro já da função js:

```html
<form method="" action="#">
<div id="cabesalho_formulario">
        <h1 id="titulo">Controle Geral de Alunos <span>(Edição)</span></h1>
        <h4 id="nome_escola">EEEP Dr. José Alves da Silveira</h4>
        <div id="atualiza" class="modal fade">
         <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
           <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Atualizar/Deletar Ocorrência</h4>
           </div>
           <div class="modal-body">
              <br class='b'><label id='just'>Justificativa: </label><br class='b'><textarea required placeholder='Digite a justificativa do aluno...' title='Seja objetivo(a).' rows='5' name = 'obs' cols='50' id='justificativa'></textarea>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" value="Atualizar">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" value="Deletar">
                     </div>
             </div>
            </div>
        </div>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode adicionar uma mensagem de alerta dinâmica acima dos botões quando der o erro especificado na sua pergunta. Caso queira outro tipo de alerta, vc pode formatar o elemento.

Primeiro crie um evento para remover o alerta quando o campo "justificativa" for focado:

```
$("#justificativa").on("focus",function(){
    $(".modal-body .msg_alerta").remove();
});
```

Depois substitua o `alert` com este código:

```
if($(".msg_alerta").length == 0){
    $(".modal-body").append('<span class="msg_alerta" style="display: block; color: #f30; margin: 10px 0;">Por favor preencha o campo Justificativa!</span>');
}
    return false;
```

```js
$("#justificativa").on("focus",function(){
 $(".modal-body .msg_alerta").remove();
});

function d(func){
   var nome = $('#nome').val();
   var data = $('#data_oco').val();
   var tipo = $('#tipo').val(); 
   var justificativa = $('#justificativa').val();
   if(justificativa==undefined){
    justificativa="";
   }else if(justificativa=="" && tipo!="Falta"){
        if($(".msg_alerta").length == 0){
    $(".modal-body").append('<span class="msg_alerta" style="display: block; color: #f30; margin: 10px 0;">Por favor preencha o campo Justificativa!</span>');
        }
    return false;
   }
   jQuery.ajax({
    method: "get",
    url: "atudel.php",
    data: { "nome": nome, "data": data, "tipo": tipo, "justificativa": justificativa, "func": func },
    success: function(data){
     alert(data);
     window.location = 'editar_ocorrencia.php';
    }
   });
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="titulo">Controle Geral de Alunos <span>(Edição)</span></h1>
    <h4 id="nome_escola">EEEP Dr. José Alves da Silveira</h4>
    <div id="atualiza" class="modal fade">
     <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Atualizar/Deletar Ocorrência</h4>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-body">
          <br class='b'><label id='just'>Justificativa: </label><br class='b'><textarea required placeholder='Digite a justificativa do aluno...' title='Seja objetivo(a).' rows='5' name = 'obs' cols='50' id='justificativa'></textarea>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="d('atualiza')">Atualizar</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="d('deleta')">Deletar</button>
                 </div>
         </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Okay, mas se eu aperto várias vezes o mesmo botão a mensagem aparece várias vezes.

Comment: @CarlosHenrique fácil de resolver. Vou atualizar.

Comment: @CarlosHenrique Apenas adicionei um IF. Abs!

Comment: Bacana. Solução simples e prática ;)

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar assim...

```
$("#IdDoForm").submit(function(event){
  event.prefentDefault(); //previne que o formulario seja enviado sem estar devidamente preenchido com as regras de validação que você definiu do client-side
 //ADICIONE AQUI SUA FUNÇÃO AJAX.
});
```

Creio que assim você conseguirá definir campos como requiridos e obrigar que eles sejam preenchidos!

Comment: Não é bem isso, que procuro, estou precisando editar o primeiro código que postei, por exemplo... Sem usar a tag form do html. Usar o required do html quando clicado no botão só que de forma que não use o alert.

Comment: Bom, sem o form você teria que criar uma função js para validar seus campos e não entrar na função ajax caso sua função de validação retorne false...

Comment: Isso, é uma função js... Que depois entrar numa função Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

## Tooltip do campo com atributo required sem um form

O atributo **required** é acionado quando o formulário for submetido.

> [**Required**: This attribute specifies that the user must fill in a value before submitting a form.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea)

Como o campo *justificativa* não está vinculado a um formulário no seu primeiro código, a mensagem de erro relativa ao campo não será exibida.

Se seu requisito é não alterar o HTML, mas ainda assim você precisa exibir as mensagens para os campos com required, você terá que implementar a mensagem por conta própria, usando Javascript, pois não terá o recurso nativo do HTML5 sem o formulário.

Comment: Como posso fazer em JavaScript?

Comment: Uma ideia para usar o recurso do HTML5: você poderia criar um form virtualmente (via Javascript) e atribuir o campo para aquele form (atributo *form*) e submeter o formulário. Não testei, mas em teoria deve funcionar.